# How to read an int from console (mips - qtspim)?

Tags: assembly, mips

```
    .data
msg1:.asciiz "Give a number: "
.text
.globl main
main:
##############################
li $v0,4
la $a0,msg1
syscall #print msg
li $v0,5
syscall #read an int
add $a0,$v0,$zero #move to $a0
##############################
jal fib #call fib

add $a0,$v0,$zero
li $v0,1
syscall

li $v0,10
syscall

fib:
#a0=y
#if (y==0) return 0;
#if (y==1) return 1;
#return( fib(y-1)+fib(y-2) );

addi $sp,$sp,-12 #save in stack
sw $ra,0($sp)
sw $s0,4($sp)
sw $s1,8($sp)

add $s0,$a0,$zero

addi $t1,$zero,1
beq $s0,$zero,return0
beq $s0,$t1,return1

addi $a0,$s0,-1

jal fib

add $s1,$zero,$v0     #s1=fib(y-1)

addi $a0,$s0,-2

jal fib               #v0=fib(n-2)

add $v0,$v0,$s1       #v0=fib(n-2)+$s1
exitfib:

lw $ra,0($sp)       #read registers from stack
lw $s0,4($sp)
lw $s1,8($sp)
addi $sp,$sp,12       #bring back stack pointer
jr $ra

return1:
 li $v0,1
 j exitfib
return0 :     li $v0,0
 j exitfib
```

This is a standard Fibonacci algorithm that demands an input at the begining of the execution.
The actual input is expected to be given by the user when the program reaches the ## ... ## delimited area.
Can someone explain please why those loads with 4 and 5 in v0 are made there?
How is this input read actually works?

Comment: The `syscall` instruction invokes the operating system which looks at the value in `$v0` to decide what service is requested. Consult your documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

same as what jester said the li $v0.. are simply syscall 'functions' that enable you to print to screen, to read input, to exit, to pause etc